# Using Grid-A-Licious plugin more than once in the same page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using [Grid-A-Licious](http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/). It works fine when I work on a single page and call that plugin once on that page, but with my design, I need to call it inside 3 tabs, so, need to call it 3 times on same page, but its not working as expected. It works perfectly with 1st tab, but fails to work on tab 2 and 3.

I'm using it with Bootstrap tabs and have 3 tabs, inside tab-content and then called **Grid-A-Licious** three times each, but its not working for me.

If anyone got the question correctly, do reply, or I will try to fiddle it up sooner!

I checked, what the issue is that, the Grid-A-Licious is not getting applied to those elements, which are hidden in inactive tabs!

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I managed it by, adding .active class to all the tabs, (they are set display:block) by default, and on ready.function, I hide the 2nd and 3rd tab, this way, gridalicious applies its styling to all tab elements, and it works.

Issue occurred due to, having other two tabs  hidden (display:none) by default, and, pluggin couldn't get the DOM elements.

But, still the issue persists, if I'm loading hude data, or fetching information from Data-base,but works fine for short static content.

Received Mails and Facebook Messages from people, asking for the code, I have used for my solution, so pasting it here. (I managed to do it - but had some issues, and later on my project there wasn't need of it, so dropped this tabbed functionality, so its not a 100% accurate solution.)

I assume, you have understanding of Bootstrap classes.

```
 <ul class="tab-menubar">
      <li class="active" ><a role="tab"data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-search">Search</a></li>
      <li><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-popular">Most Popular</a></li>
      <li><a role="tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-fav">Favourites</a></li>
 </ul>

<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-search">
   <div class="gridalacious-wrapper">
      <div class="item">
         <your HTML>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-popular"></div>
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-fav"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tab-popular, #tab-fav').removeClass('active');
 });
```